# rails gem Make_flaggable doesn't save to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, voting-system

Just went through the tutorial, set everything up. When I ran the command line test it seems that methods are picking up the right data, but not saving them into db.

```
irb(main):009:0> u.flag(s, :promote)
  MakeFlaggable::Flagging Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "flaggings".* FROM "flaggings" WHERE "flaggings"."flagger_id" = 2 AND "flaggings"."flagger_type" = 'User' AND "flaggings"."flaggable_type" = 'Scribble' AND "flaggings"."flaggable_id" = 48 AND "flaggings"."flag" = 'promote' LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO "flaggings" ("created_at", "flag", "flaggable_id", "flaggable_type", "flagger_id", "flagger_type", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Wed, 12 Mar 2014 20:15:45 UTC +00:00], ["flag", nil], ["flaggable_id", nil], ["flaggable_type", nil], ["flagger_id", nil], ["flagger_type", nil], ["updated_at", Wed, 12 Mar 2014 20:15:45 UTC +00:00]]
   (12.0ms)  COMMIT
=> #<MakeFlaggable::Flagging id: 10, flaggable_type: nil, flaggable_id: nil, flagger_type: nil, flagger_id: nil, flag: nil, created_at: "2014-03-12 20:15:45", updated_at: "2014-03-12 20:15:45">
```

As you can see the method Selects all the right data, but saves only nils.
Does anyone know what might be the problem with this ?

Comment: I had the same problem, and was never able to solve.

Comment: I kinda really want to solve it :)

Comment: If no one answers it within a few days I'll put a bounty on it.

Comment: I also asked on github and on the video tutorial in comments, maybe one of the developers of the gem will be willing to help out.

Comment: What version are you using? Could you share entire project (I guess this is just tutorial) or at least Gemfile. Because the SQL your project generates is different from that you can get on fresh project: `SELECT "flaggings".* FROM "flaggings" WHERE "flaggings"."flagger_id" = 1 AND "flaggings"."flagger_type" = 'User' AND "flaggings"."flaggable_type" = 'Article' AND "flaggings"."flaggable_id" = 1 LIMIT 1`. Something is is mixing `AND "flaggings"."flag" = 'promote'` to conditions.

Comment: The sencond SQL is also different `INSERT INTO "flaggings" ("created_at", "flaggable_id", "flaggable_type", "flagger_id", "flagger_type", "reason", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sun, 16 Mar 2014 20:52:50 UTC +00:00], ["flaggable_id", 1], ["flaggable_type", "Article"], ["flagger_id", 1], ["flagger_type", "User"], ["reason", :promote], ["updated_at", Sun, 16 Mar 2014 20:52:50 UTC +00:00]]`. In general the schema doesn't have `flag` column for `flaggings` at all

Comment: https://github.com/medihack/make_flaggable/blob/master/lib/generators/make_flaggable/templates/migration.rb#L3-L11 This is how your schema for flaggable should look like

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the problem. I used rails 3.2.16 and the gem from github.
Two settings seem to cause the problem.
First, you have to have this line in your application.rb:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

The other setting is

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
```

If you have the above line in your environment file, the app would have thrown an exception when you tried to user.flag(article, :promote) because the gem does not whitelists it's attributes.

I guess you do not have the strict setting, because without it the app acts like how your app did. It does not throw an exception, just ignores the values and saves the record with null values.
(Note: although the app should give you a warning like this:

> WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: flaggable, flagger,
>   reason

but it is easy to miss that in the log).

Now, that we know what seems to be the problem, we could try to fix it.
Without changing anything in the gem, you can just disable whitelist_attributes by changing true to false in application.rb

However this is not a proper fix, just a workaround to show how it would work, the gem should take care it's own attributes and it should not require you to use a specific setting for your app (eg. to disable whitelist_attributes completely)

Comment: Thank You, I'll try the temp fix once I'm at home tonight

Comment: Unfortunately Sir, I still get the same results. The whitelist was false all along, that's why didn't get the mass assignment error. And the :strict is there. with whitelist = false it saves an empty set.

Comment: Hm, weird then. I'm pretty sure what I wrote is related to your issue. It would make sense. Could you maybe post your Gemfile, Gemfile.lock so I can check with the exact versions?

Comment: Could you please also try to change whitelist to true and see if you have the same warning/error I posted above?

Comment: Ok, but for the same 3 attributes (flaggable, flagger, reason)? or is there anything else beside those?